Sharing Rule Filter Criteria Error
I need to create one Sharing rule with the following:
Based on Criteria:

Record Type == Vendor (Payee) AND Vendor_Type == 'Vantive' OR
Vendor_Type == 'Baxter'

I am receiving the filter logic error as attached in the image. So, can someone help me in resolving this issue?


Can you please try to clear the filter logic and add it again? Make sure that each filter is defined before referencing it in the filter logic.

Hi @TusharJadav, i have cleared the filter logic and added it again, but still the same error. May i please know on how to define filter logic reference here? Thanks

Steps to Define Filter Logic in Sharing Rules


Define the Criteria Filters:
•  Filter 1: Record Type == Vendor (Payee)
•  Filter 2: Vendor_Type == 'Vantive'
•  Filter 3: Vendor_Type == 'Baxter'


Set the Filter Logic:
•  The filter logic should be: 1 AND (2 OR 3)


Make sure that each filter (1, 2, and 3) is defined before referencing them in the filter logic.

I have set filter logic 1 AND (2 OR 3) but still receiving the same error. Is there any other way? @tushar jadhav

Any chance that your user doesn't have access to those record types? Even as a system admin sometimes those miscellaneous permission issues can come up if the record type isn't assigned, or perhaps it's inactive.
